# How to sort object array?

Tags: java

I have an object array like

```
Player p[] = new Player[t];
```

And every object has an integer variable and a name variable.

```
public class Player {
   public String player_name;
   public int number;
}
```

After getting input from user how can I sort this object array according to their number variable?

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property?rq=1 (it's for a List, then see [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)))

Comment: Read about `Arrays.sort` and `Comparator`

Comment: Turn your eyes on the right, to the "Related" section, and you'll find dozens of duplicates of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to make `Player` implement `Comparable<Player>`, and implement the `compareTo(Player)` method inside `Player`:

```
public int compareTo(Player player) {
  return this.number-player.number;
}
```

Then, wherever you want to sort the array, just call `Arrays.sort(p);`

Comment: Note that this might not work for large negative values of number. Better use `Integer.compare`

Answer (score 1):

With Java SE 8 try something like (untested):

```
Arrays.stream(p).sorted((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.number, p2.number)) .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**Edit**

On second thought this might be more efficient in this case, as it doesn't create a new array/ collection:

```
Arrays.sort(p, (p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.number, p2.number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements `Comparator<Player>`, called say `PlayerComparator`.  Implement the interface by creating a [`compare` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) that takes two `Player`s.  Return a negative number, zero, or a positive number, depending on whether the first `Player` is considered less than, equal to, or greater than, the second `Player`.

Then you can create your `PlayerComparator` and pass it (along with your array) to [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 0):

let your custom class implements `Comparable` interface and then you can use java Collection to sort your array (`Arrays.sort()` function)

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
   public String player_name;
   public int number;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Player object) {
        return this.player_name.compareTo(object.player_name);
    }
}
```

**sort**

```
Player p[] = new Player[t];
// do stuff
Arrays.sort(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have a getter on the number variable for this to work, like:

```
public class Player {
   public String player_name;
   public int number;

   public int getNumber() {
       return number;
   }
}
```

Then, as of Java 8, you can sort it by using the `Comparing` factory class:

```
Player[] p = new Player[t];
Arrays.sort(p, Comparator.comparingInt(Player::getNumber));
```

This will:

- Create a `Comparator<Person>`, by comparing no the `getNumber` method.
- What you see here is a method reference, which is shorthand for the lambda `p -> player.getNumber()`, which maps the player to the number.